# How to send Array of objects to stored procedure from nodejs express?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, typescript

thanks in advance. Here i want to send a array of objects to the stored procedure via mssql connection to the ms sql-server from NodeJs backend. i have submitted my Stored Procedure and Backend code block.

--- Stored Procedure ---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddProductVariant]
@ProductId BIGINT ,
@Name NVARCHAR(200) ,
@InputTypeId TINYINT ,
@Attributes dbo.UT_ProductVariant READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @Id BIGINT
        INSERT  INTO dbo.ProductVariants
                ( ProductId, Name, InputTypeId )
        VALUES  ( @ProductId -- ProductId - bigint
                  , @Name -- Name - nvarchar(50)
                  , @InputTypeId  -- InputTypeId - tinyint
                  )
        SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        EXECUTE MergeProductVariantAttributes @Id, @Attributes

        SELECT  *
        FROM    SellEasyDb.dbo.ProductVariants
        WHERE   Id = @Id
        --SELECT * FROM SellEasyDb.dbo.UserGroups WHERE SellEasyDb.dbo.UserGroups.Id = @Id
        RETURN 0
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        RETURN @@ERROR
    END CATCH

END
```

--- NODE TS CODE ---

```
    const pool = dbConnect.connect();
    const request = dbConnect.request();
    request.input("ProductId", req.body.productId);
    request.input("Name", req.body.name);
    request.input("InputTypeId", req.body.inputTypeId);
    request.input("Attributes", req.body.attributes); // this is the array i want to send to SP

    await request.execute("AddProductVariant", async (err: any, result: any, resultvalue: any) => {
        debugger;
        }
    });
```

--- ERROR ---

```
class:16
code:'EREQUEST'
lineNumber:0
message:'Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with UT_ProductVariant'
name:'RequestError'
number:206
state:2
```

--- User Define Type ---

```
CREATE TYPE UT_ProductVariant AS TABLE  
(  
    [Id] [BIGINT],
    [Title] [VARCHAR](200) NOT NULL,
    [PriceAdjustment] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [IsDefault] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [SortOrder] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [VarientId] [BIGINT],
    [ProductId] [BIGINT]
)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the definition of the `dbo.UT_ProductVariant` user-defined type.

Comment: Yup check now its just User Define Type